# Oracle SQL Developer - format query output

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got this simple query:

```
select e.empname.title, e.empname.firstname, e.empname.surname 
from employee e
where e.empname.firstName like '%on%' and e.empaddress.city like 'New York';
```

I'm using objects, and im trying to format the columns on the query results, so it shows 'Title', 'First name' and 'Surname'instead of the types ive created i've tried adding the following above the query, and a few other variations with no luck.

```
COLUMN E.EMPNAME.TITLE    HEADING 'Title'
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e.empname.title as Title , e.empname.firstname as Firstname, e.empname.surname as Surname
from employee e
where e.empname.firstName like '%on%' and e.empaddress.city like 'New York';
```